# Class name as Variable

Tags: powershell, class, variables

OK, I am totally new to OOP in general, and trying to learn it in PowerShell 5.0. I have this working code which is great.

```
class Animal {
    [string]$name
    [int]$legs
    [int]$age
    [int]$weightLbs
    [int]$heightInches

    Animal() {
    }
    Animal([string]$name) {
        $this.name = $name 
    }

    [string]Jump() {
        return  "look at that $($this.ToString()) jump!"
    }

    [string]Speak() {
        throw [notImplementedException]::New('Speak method should be overridden in child class')
    }
}

class Dog : Animal {
    [int]$tailLength

    Dog() {
    }
    Dog([string]$name)  : base($name) {
    }

    [int]AgeDogYears() {
        return $this.age * 7
    }
    [string]Speak() {
        return 'woof!'
    }
}


CLS

$rottweiler = [Dog]::new('Rottweiler')
$rottweiler.AgeDogYears()
$rottweiler.Jump()
$rottweiler.Speak()
```

However, in the code I actually need to implement, I will be extracting data from XML and I need to reference a specific Class based on that data. When using Functions I can have a function name in a variable that is assigned from the XML data, then call that function. But when I try something similar with classes, like this ...

```
$className = 'Dog'
$boxer = [$className]::new('Boxer')
```

... it's a no go. Is there a mechanism for this, or am I going to have to use a Switch statement or the like and address all possible class names there, which then requires coordinating that statement with any new Classes I create?

Also, if the Class name as Variable option exists, I would then need to test to make sure the Class actually exists, in case there is a type in the XML. For example if the XML had God while the Class should be Dog. So far I am not finding a way to test for the existence of a class other than a Try/Catch. Is that my only option, or is there a better way? I try to limit Try/Catch to unexpected things. So, for example I don't take an argument for a folder path to Remove-Item on and wrap it in a Try/Catch, I Test-Path first, provide an error in the log if the target isn't found, then use Try/Catch for things like the target having permissions that inhibit the delete. Seems a better approach to me.

EDIT: OK, trying to extrapolate on @josefz 's post, and I tried this and a few variations, to get something with every reference to a Class or Variable name in a variable. I feel like I am SO close.

```
$newClass = 'Dog'
$newDog = 'Boxer'

New-Variable -name:($newDog) -value:$($newClass -as [type])::new($newDog)
(Get-Variable -name:($newDog)).Jump()
```

EDIT2: So, I still seem to be having problems integrating classes with New-Variable, but as for testing if a class exists this works a treat. So that part is solved.

```
if (($testClass -as [type])) {
    Write-Host "$testClass is a valid class"
} else {
    Write-Host "$testClass is not a valid class"
}
```

Also, I would probably end up with things organised in a hash table or something, not individual Variables. And this also works fine.

```
$dogs = @('rottweiler', 'boxer')
$dogObjects = @{}
foreach ($dog in $dogs) {
    $dogObjects.Add($dog, [Dog]::new($dog))
}
foreach ($key in $dogObjects.keys) {
    Write-Host "$($dogObjects.$key.Jump())"
}
```

Comment: `$className = 'Dog'; $boxer = $($className -as [type])::new('Boxer')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
[string]Jump() {
    return  "look at that $($this.ToString()) jump!"
}
```

to

```
[string]Jump() {
    return  "look at that $($this.name) jump!"
}
```

you can use declared classes e.g. as follows:

```
$rottweiler = [Dog]::new('Rottweiler')
$rottweiler.AgeDogYears()
$rottweiler.Jump()
$rottweiler.Speak()

# another use case:
$auxObject=@"
species,breed,note
Dog,husky,valid
Int,beagle,invalid: ('Int' -as [type]) returns System.ValueType
NaN,collie,invalid: ('NaN' -as [type]) returns Null
Cat,bobtail,invalid: 'Cat' isn't defined yet as Animal class
Dog,bulldog,valid
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ','

foreach ( $aux in $auxObject) {
    $ClassType = $aux.Species -as [type]
    if ( $ClassType -and $ClassType.BaseType.FullName -eq 'Animal' ) {
        '---'
        $aDog = $ClassType::new($aux.Breed)
        $aDog.AgeDogYears()
        $aDog.Jump()
        $aDog.Speak()
    }
}
```

Output: `.\SO\57767613.ps1`

> ```
> 0
> look at that Rottweiler jump!
> woof!
> ---
> 0
> look at that husky jump!
> woof!
> ---
> 0
> look at that bulldog jump!
> woof!
> ```

**Edit**: yet another use case - a **Hashtable**

```
$Animals = @{}
foreach ( $aux in $auxObject) {
    $ClassType = $aux.Species -as [type]
    if ( $ClassType -and $ClassType.BaseType.FullName -eq 'Animal' ) {
        $Animals[$aux.breed] = $ClassType::new($aux.Breed)
    }
}

$Animals.Rottweiler.Jump()
$Animals.Rottweiler.Speak()

$Animals.Husky.Jump()
$Animals.Husky.Speak()

$aDog = 'bulldog'
$Animals.$aDog.Jump()
$Animals.$aDog.Speak()
```

**Output**: `D:\PShell\SO\57767613a.ps1`

> ```
> look at that Rottweiler jump!
> woof!
> look at that husky jump!
> woof!
> look at that bulldog jump!
> woof!
> ```

**Note**:

```
$Animals.$aDog | Get-Member
```

> ```
>    TypeName: Dog
>
> Name         MemberType Definition                    
> ----         ---------- ----------                    
> AgeDogYears  Method     int AgeDogYears()             
> Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
> GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()             
> GetType      Method     type GetType()                
> Jump         Method     string Jump()                 
> Speak        Method     string Speak()                
> ToString     Method     string ToString()             
> age          Property   int age {get;set;}            
> heightInches Property   int heightInches {get;set;}   
> legs         Property   int legs {get;set;}           
> name         Property   string name {get;set;}        
> tailLength   Property   int tailLength {get;set;}     
> weightLbs    Property   int weightLbs {get;set;}
> ```

Comment: That works to loop through different Species, but they are all in a variable called $aDog, and not persistent. What if I need to end up with Variables called $rottweiler, $husky, etc? That's what I was getting at on my last attempt, using a variable to define the name of the variable that would be created.

Comment: @Gordon Answer updated. Using variables called `$rottweiler`, `$husky` etc. seems to be a bit unpractical.  There is an object called [hashtable](https://www.google.com/search?&q=hashtable+powershell)…